# Change Bootstrap 5 error message's language Laravel 10

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing an app using Laravel 10 and Bootstrap 5. I have installed Laravel UI and everything is working fine, except I want to change the language of Bootstrap's error messages from English to French. How can I achieve this?

https://imgur.com/a/Q3yVMdl

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This might help: [Localization](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/localization)

Comment: @linktoahref Thank you, i searched for Laravel Localization in Laravel's docs and that's exactly what i wanted.